# Displaying thumbnail image in a View

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I've a database with image (1 document contains 1 image).
This database is used in other application via "PickList" so user can select image they want (right now they just see a filename and that's it). Once user selected an image - we display it in IBM Notes client via html. However the issue is - user must guess if he select the right image and to avoid 'guessing' I would like to show thumbnail version of image in PickList.

So far I found only one way to do that (for every image I've in database I will create a image resource element in design. In that way I can display it in a View (in a column).

What other ways to achieve this you know?
Please consider any ways you know, I'm not limited to using views only, it could be Dialogs, generating something in RTF field dynamically, OLE, Java etc. Basically I'm very very open minded to another solution.

Environment: #IBM Domino/Notes R9.

Comment: In Notes Client only, the only way with views is to have an ImageRessource for each thumbnail. Don't forget that creating these resources needs designer rights. Other possibility is to have a frameset. One frame shows the view, the other frame shows just the image.

Comment: Or you could write your own Java-Applet ...

Comment: You are right, I already mentioned that I know this way and looking for something out of the box :-).
But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Domino 9, how about developing in XPages?  If you are going to switch to an HTML frame in the Notes client to look at the image anyway, you may as well select from an HTML frame, too.  You can use XPages for Notes clients, not just web clients.

Using common XPage controls, you can develop dynamic HTML pages from Notes views and documents.  You could for example develop an XPage to display a list of choices from a view - including file attachment names and/or the actual file attachments.

It is absolutely doable with XPages.  Checkout OpenNTF.org for lots of examples.

Comment: It's not an option. 30 LS classes, at least 20 forms with dialogs, 50++ views etc.